# LEFT JOIN vs one table

Tags: sql-server, join

The company I work for often splits entities across multiple tables for performance reasons because only a small percentage of them will have those properties. An entity Item would have its properties split across two to seven tables as normalization commands. **Is this a viable strategy?**

I ran the queries below and compared a LEFT JOIN with a complete table (the last two queries). Why is the LEFT JOIN slower? All over this forum you read about how relational databases should handle these no problem. Yet the execution plan estimates the full table query at 11% of the batch cost. The client statistics also favor the complete table by a small margin.

Am I missing something in my queries? Or is a LEFT JOIN just slower than a complete table?

[Comparison of LEFT JOIN vs one table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkxNS.png)

[Comparison of LEFT JOIN vs one table(2): here you can clearly see the second query is slower in seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOBfm.png)

```
CREATE TABLE
    [Item] (
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Property1] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Property2] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property3] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property4] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property5] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property6] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property7] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property8] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property9] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property10] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property11] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property12] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property13] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property14] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property15] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property16] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property17] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property18] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property19] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property20] VARCHAR(50) NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Item] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];
GO

DECLARE @i INT = 106
WHILE @i < 3009286
BEGIN
    EXEC ('INSERT INTO [Item] ([Property1]) VALUES (' + @i + ')');
    EXEC ('INSERT INTO [Item2] ([Property1]) VALUES (' + @i + ')');
    SET @i = @i + 1
END

CREATE TABLE
    [Item2] (
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Property1] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Item2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];
GO


CREATE TABLE
    [ItemProperties1] (
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ItemId] INT NOT NULL,
    [Property1] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Property2] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property3] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property4] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property5] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property6] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property7] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property8] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property9] VARCHAR(50) NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ItemProperties1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];
GO


CREATE TABLE
    [ItemProperties2] (
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ItemId] INT NOT NULL,
    [Property10] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property11] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property12] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property13] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property14] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property15] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property16] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property17] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property18] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property19] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Property20] VARCHAR(50) NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ItemProperties2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ItemProperties_ItemId] ON [ItemProperties1]
(
    [ItemId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ItemProperties_ItemId] ON [ItemProperties2]
(
    [ItemId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SELECT
    *
FROM
    Item

SELECT
    *
FROM
    Item2
LEFT JOIN
    ItemProperties1 ON Item2.Id = ItemProperties1.ItemId
LEFT JOIN
    ItemProperties2 ON Item2.Id = ItemProperties2.ItemId
```

Comment: Why the double id? If each record can only have one row in each table, use a single  (clustered) primary key. Will make it impossible to suddenly have two rows for a record and it's physically stored in the right order.  And what's with the 11% faster? 10ms or 11,1ms? Handle it perfectly does not mean always faster.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree. It allows enforcing of data integrity as well as saving one column. This is also a discussion I am currently having with our DBA but it sadly fell on deaf ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is this a viable strategy?** 
Yes it is, it is called *vertical sharding/vertical partitioning*. The idea behind it is a percentage of your columns will be used more, so the idea is to put these columns on faster hardware, also depending on how you implement the sharding it will make the indexes smaller and thus fit more on a *page*. But we need to know how your company is *vertically sharding/vertical partitioning* the database. Are you truely using partitioned tables? Or did some DBA just slap two indexes on both tables and referenced them?

For example (without using MS table partitioning)

Table A: 
id
Col A
Col B

Table A partitioned table
Id
Col C
Col D

Taking a guess as to why the left join is slower (because I don't know how you are *sharding/partitioning* your table, is that it has to do a 2 *clustered index scans* to pull up the data, then use the *nested join* to bring the data together then scan the partitioned table and use a nested join to bring that data back together.

So It has to do much more work to make the data look like it is logically one table.

***EDIT***

I didn't look at your code fully, you are not using microsofts partition table functionality.[This is a good base walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/create-partitioned-tables-and-indexes)

***EDIT***
If you are going to use partition tables you need several things, i doubt you are using any of these. But if you can find a partition function in your db and a partition schema then your company is probably partitioning tables.

1. [A partition function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-partition-function-transact-sql)
2. [A partition schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-partition-scheme-transact-sql)

Comment: How can I check your questions, specifically: "are you truly using partioned tables?"

Comment: Your create scripts are not using partitioned table functionality by MS. The document I linked to is a good walk through of how to tell and what they are.

Comment: using the script found on your link "to determine whether a table is partioned" yielded no results. I assume that this means the latter in your scenario and we are in no way taking advantage of this strategy's power. Probably even making it worse?

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, JOINs are slower than having everything in one table: even if it is optimized, you still need to lookup the same value in more than one place. It is also generally true that if you return more data (or columns) to an application than it needs, you will have a performance hit just because of cost of transfer.

***Is this viable?*** Yes. Almost every CMS does something similar, and last I checked WordPress is fairly important.

***Is this a good idea?*** Define "good". This will generally let you have a smaller, highly performant table which you are free to join with smaller data tables as required. This means that you should have an easier time at joining against other sources as needed.

***Will this hurt performance?*** If you can manage even a minor increase in performance for 89% of the rows, that will make up for an 11% decrease in the performance of the other rows.

Comment: The thing is, these are entities which as a rule are selected from the database as ONE, meaning the entire set of for example seven tables is queried. The only reason I've heard mentioned at work for this entity splitting so far is because a lot of records don't have to be created then which causes an increase in performance. Is this still a good idea then?

Comment: If you always use all the columns, then it doesn't seem like it will benefit. If you sometimes use all the columns and mostly only use some of the columns, then it might be beneficial.